# Why different lightbox links are opening always the same content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

So, I'm trying show different contents in different links for lightboxes, but when I click, I just can see the last content lightbox link open in all others. Overlapping the others I believe.

```
<div class="servicos lightbox"> 
    <a><h3> BOX ONE </h3></a> 
</div>
<div class="background"></div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="close">
        <h4>X</h4>
    </div>
    <h1> HERE WE SEE 1° CONTENT </h1>
</div>
<div class="servicos lightbox"> 
    <a><h3> BOX TWO </h3></a> 
</div>
<div class="background"></div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="close">
        <h4>X</h4>
    </div>
    <h1> HERE WE SEE 2° CONTENT </h1>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.lightbox').click(function () {
        $('.background, .box').animate({
            'opacity': '.50'
        }, 500, 'linear');
        $('.box').animate({
            'opacity': '1.00'
        }, 500, 'linear');
        $('.background, .box').css('display', 'block');
    });

    $('.close').click(function () {
        $('.background, .box').animate({
            'opacity': '0'
        }, 500, 'linear', function () {
            $('.background, .box').css('display', 'none');
        });;
    });

    $('.background').click(function () {
        $('.background, .box').animate({
            'opacity': '0'
        }, 500, 'linear', function () {
            $('.background, .box').css('display', 'none');
        });;
    });
});
```

```css
.background {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 102;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image:url(../imagens/bg_litghbox.gif);
    z-index:105;
    overflow: auto;
}
.box {
    position:absolute;
    width: 70%;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    z-index:106;
    padding:14px;
    border-radius:1em;
    -moz-border-radius:1em;
    -webkit-border-radius:1em;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #333333;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #333333;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #333333;
    display:none;
    overflow:auto;
}
.close {
    float:right;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: You need to refine the selector's scope, `.background, .box` would apply effects to _All_ `.box`, not only the one your click target related to.

Comment: thanks for attention @fuyushimoya but can you explain how can I do that? I was tried many things but I do not have knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use [.nextUntil](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) to get the following `.box` and `.background` and only apply animation to them.
2. Or you can wrap them into a container, then use [.siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to get them.
3. It may be better to have only one `.background`, and move it to the last of the html, if you're not applying different background css to each of the lightbox's background.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.lightbox').click(function () {
      // Get all following .box and .background until next .lightbox is met.
      // So we can get the related contents.
      var $targets = $(this).nextUntil('.lightbox', '.box, .background');
        $targets.animate({
            'opacity': '.50'
        }, 500, 'linear')
        
        $targets.filter('.box').animate({
            'opacity': '1.00'
        }, 500, 'linear');
      
        $targets.css('display', 'block');
    });

    $('.close').click(function () {
        $('.background, .box').animate({
            'opacity': '0'
        }, 500, 'linear', function () {
            $('.background, .box').css('display', 'none');
        });;
    });

    $('.background').click(function () {
        $('.background, .box').animate({
            'opacity': '0'
        }, 500, 'linear', function () {
            $('.background, .box').css('display', 'none');
        });;
    });
});
```

```css
.background {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 102;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image:url(../imagens/bg_litghbox.gif);
    z-index:105;
    overflow: auto;
}
.box {
    position:absolute;
    width: 70%;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    z-index:106;
    padding:14px;
    border-radius:1em;
    -moz-border-radius:1em;
    -webkit-border-radius:1em;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #333333;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #333333;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #333333;
    display:none;
    overflow:auto;
}
.close {
    float:right;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="servicos lightbox"> 
    <a><h3> BOX ONE </h3></a> 
</div>
<div class="background"></div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="close">
        <h4>X</h4>
    </div>
    <h1> HERE WE SEE 1° CONTENT </h1>
</div>
<div class="servicos lightbox"> 
    <a><h3> BOX TWO </h3></a> 
</div>
<div class="background"></div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="close">
        <h4>X</h4>
    </div>
    <h1> HERE WE SEE 2° CONTENT </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I probably could not solve this, cause I'm beginner yet, but thank you @fuyushimoya.

Comment: Forgive me that English is not my native language, is 'could not solve this' means you're not sure you completely know how the changes make the code to work? If so, feel free to ask , otherwise, you're welcome :).

Comment: Relax, it's not my native language too :) Actually I said that today I do not have skills to solve like you did. Then, I seek to learn more. @fuyushimoya